# VBA excel web page click with no id tag

Tags: excel, vba, web

Apologies if this question has been asked before . I have tried other solutions and they don't appear to work me. I am trying to use VBA to click on a search button but I get no response. The button HTML is as follows

```
     <span id="searchButton">
       <button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: 
      GetFilteredRequests.bind($data, 1)">
         <span id="innerSeachButton" class="fa fa-search">&nbsp;
     </span>Search
     </button>
      </span>
```

I was trying something like this but it doesn't work;

```
  Dim e
  For Each e In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
  If InStr(e.outerHTML, "btn btn-default") > 0 Then
     Stop
    e.Click
    Exit For

 End If
 Next
```

Comment: instead of searching "span", try "button". I think span don't have click event. Also "btn btn-default" is present in button outerhtml, not in span outerhtml

Comment: Try `ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default")(0).click`